# Not able to delete file from the server?

Tags: filesystems

I've a file called piture-list.php in my website.

When I see them through the ftp client it shows two files with different filesizes.

as

```
File name          filesize
picture-list.php   19818
picture-list.php   9063
```

When I select the file with filesize 9063 and delete using ftp, it deletes the file with the filesize 19818.

Then I used the command prompt to list files and happened to see actually there were two files one with the original name and other with a space before the filename (" picture-list.php").

I tried to move, delete the file but nothing is successful..

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interact with the file containing a leading space you will need to put a quotes around the file name e.g.

```
rm " picture-list.php"
```

You can also use the `-i` command line switch e.g.

```
rm -i *pict*
rm: remove regular file ` picture-list.php'?
```

and answer y to remove the one with the leading space.